# How to show records in database in a gridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview

```
    Private Sub frmSearchRecords_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load         
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand         
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader         
    cmd.Connection = con          
    connect()         
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from tblconsumer order by ConsumerID"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        With grdView
            .Rows.Add()
            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(0).Value = dr(0).ToString
            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(1).Value = dr(1).ToString
            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(2).Value = dr(2).ToString
            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(3).Value = dr(3).ToString
            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(4).Value = dr(4).ToString
            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(5).Value = dr(5).ToString
            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(6).Value = dr(6).ToString
        End With
    End While
    disconnect()
    End Sub
```

> can anyone help me fix this one, i have this gridview in database and i cant load the records in the database in this gridview

Comment: Please make your question more specific. For example it would be nice to mention that Windows Forms *DataGridView* is being used and not ASP.NET *GridView*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code applicable form Windows Forms not applicable to Asp.net
to follow below method or Yuriy Galanter Method

```
Private Sub frmSearchRecords_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load         
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand         
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader         
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    cmd.Connection = con          
    connect()         
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from tblconsumer order by ConsumerID"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
    If Not dt IsNothing Andalso dt.Rows.Count >0 Then
    grdView.DataSource =dt
    grdView.DataBind()
    End If
    disconnect()
End Sub
```

Comment: OP should've mentioned that Windows Forms *DataGridView* is being used. From the context of the question it seems like ASP.NET *GridView*